# OnetoOneField connection , can't access the related information , django

Tags: python, django

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='oser')
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_images', blank=True)
```

So, I've added picture to user profile , it works good , but I can't access picture to show it in user profile

***view.py:***

```
def profile(request):
if request.user.is_authenticated():
    user = User.objects.get_by_natural_key(request.user.get_username())
    t = loader.get_template("profile.html")
    c = Context({'user2': user, })
    return HttpResponse(t.render(c))
else:
    raise Http404
```

What I've found in django docs

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    department = models.CharField(max_length=100)

u = User.objects.get(username='fsmith')
freds_department = u.employee.department
```

However, this doesn't work for me , I just can't get UserProfile.picture

```
u = User.objects.get(username= request.user.get_username())
s = u.UserProfile.picture
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use "related name", which specified in foreign key field, to access user profile, not class name:

```
s = u.oser.picture
```

By default "related_name" is the same as related model class name, but in lowercase. You specified related_name="oser".